# .NET 8 MAUI resume application and refresh UI

Tags: c#, maui, .net-8.0

I'm creating a new application using .NET 8 MAUI. On a page, I have a `ListView` that receives the data to display from the *view model*. When the page is open, using the event `OnAppearing()`, the application populates the `ListView`.

I notice that if after this activity, I send in background the application and then recover it from the background, the application shows only a partial `ListView`. To see all the items again, I have to refresh the `ListView` or go back and reopen the page.

I tried to use the `OnResume()` but I don't know what to do with it. Do I have to save the status of the application in same way?

Comment: please post the relevant code